# Importing of specific .scss file breaks Git?

Tags: git, import, sass, tracking

Have you ever had a change in a file that has prevented git from seeing the appropriate changes? I ran into this bizarre git behavior today. Consider a file, main.scss, which @imports .scss partials. Everyday scenario, 100% easy, always, right? no problem. Until today!

[image: imports]

When I attempted to import a file with the path "layout/sidebars/header" (pointing to the corresponding and extant /layout/sidebars/header.scss file), I observed strange/curious/troubling behavior out of *git*.

Upon adding the line, git status produced a clean status, but an unresponsive one. i.e. Touching new files did not register any changes. This behavior is exemplified in the image below, and I hope it can prove satisfactory to show the curious nature:

When I attempt to move the file to a new one, called "test.scss", or even "test.test" (for the .gitignore skeptics), I do not get a clean chance to commit the newly added file as I expect.

[image: Moving file]

Git has stopped tracking files cleanly based on this line in the code, and this is a recipe for disaster --- as one could then successfully build on their own machine, and, one might out of some irresponsible habit make the mistake of using "git add --all", assuming that the included file was there to be staged in that commit. If that developer should push too quickly out of habit or used some other piped command, the problem has reached the repository.

What would cause this? Nobody likes broken code in a commit... but this is the first time in my experience where it seems code *within* a file has broken my Git's ability to track the files properly?

I had kind of perceived Git as being agnostic to a file's contents, simply dealing with bit-modes and bytes... so the idea that an included file would break Git is strange to me.

Any insights or theories on this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `git move` instead of `mv`. It is clear the file will be deleted when you `mv`. And for other problems ... you may use `git reflog` and restore previous states ... and then just try again.

Comment: And ... stupid question ... did you saved your changes?

Answer (score 4):

You ran (as is visible in your second image):

```
mv main.scss test.scss
```

This altered your *work-tree*, but not your *index*.<sup>1</sup>  Of course, your current or `HEAD` commit is unchanged.

Since `git status` runs two separate `git diff`s (more or less), here's what `git status` makes of this:

1. Compare `HEAD` vs index: nothing has changed at all.

   Therefore, since nothing is different, nothing is as yet staged for commit.
2. Compare index vs work-tree.  Hm, the file `main.scss` is in the index, but not in the work-tree.  It must have been deleted!

   Since the work-tree file is gone, you must eventually intend to delete `main.scss`.  However, since you have not yet asked Git to remove it from the index, it will continue to be in the next commit.  So this deletion is not yet *staged for commit*.  You can of course request that it be staged for commit at any point from here forward.

It's not clear whether there is a file named `test.scss` in your index.<sup>2</sup>  If there isn't, the new `test.scss` that just showed up in your work-tree is an *untracked* file.  It may or may not also be ignored—if it's not ignored, `git status` will complain about it, saying that it is untracked.  If it's both untracked *and* ignored, `git status` will be quiet about it.  Ignore rules can be introduced from sneaky locations, so **use `git check-ignore -v` to find out more here.**

Note that if you use `git mv` instead of plain `mv`, Git will simultaneously rename the file in your work-tree *and* rename the file in your index.  You will then have no `main.scss` in your index (so that it will be scheduled to be deleted on the next commit), and will have a `test.scss` in both index and work-tree.

Because `git status`'s `git diff` operations do *rename detection*, Git will compare the old `main.scss` with the new `test.scss`, find that it is identical, and say that you *renamed* the file.  (In fact, the next commit will merely lack `main.scss` and have `test.scss`—but *other* comparisons will *also* detect the rename, and report it as one, provided you ask Git to detect renames.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that the index—also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, depending on who is doing the calling—is where you build your *next* commit to make.  It starts out matching the commit you checked out by running `git checkout branch`: that is, it has a copy of every file, in the special Git-only format that Git uses, just like the `HEAD` commit.

The key difference between the copy in the index and the copy in the `HEAD` commit is that the copy in the index *can* be modified, or removed entirely; and files that are not yet in the index can be added into it.  Since the *next* commit you will make is built out of whatever is in the index when you run `git commit`, it's your job to build up the new index.  But since files in the index are in this special, compressed, Git-only form, Git copies those files out into your *work-tree* as well, where you can work on them.  Using `git add path` copies the file back into the index, overwriting the version that was there before—or if there was none there before, creates that file *in* the index.

<sup>2</sup>To see *everything* that's in your index, use `git ls-files --stage`.  This is pretty verbose, though.  Usually it's much more interesting to view the index in terms of what's *different*, which is why `git status` diffs HEAD-vs-index, then index-vs-work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

A paticularly wicked merge had come in from master within the *parent* .git module and ultimately turned out to be responsible for including my working directory (git submodule) within the .gitignore. Thus, any file I created was never served up to `git status` was not included for staging.

As @Torek pointed out, the adjustment vs. the index appropriately responded... this one was simply deceptive because I could not find a corresponding .gitignore rule within my *working* git repository that made any sense.

Dig deep, but don't forget to search higher.

Comment: BTW, `git check-ignore -v` is sometimes *very* helpful here!